# Getting current project's path

Tags: qt, qt-creator

How to get absolute path of current active project opened in qtCreator?  Is there a way to do it anyway?

Comment: Where do you want to get that information? Are you developing a QtCreator plugin?

Comment: #FrankOsterfeld yes, I do.

Comment: For interfaces in Qtcreator, you'll have to read qtcreator sourcecode and see http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator#a16b6d01b077c1e317a63fc55fb81ad2 for IRC channels And mailing lists. There isn't public documentation or much external knowledge about Qt creator development to be found on SO etc.

Comment: #FrankOsterfeld thanks for the link, I'll give it a go. Regards

Comment: There's actually apidocs, see nicolas smith's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt only has support for `QDir::currentPath` which will point to where the executable is, as far as I'm aware it's got no hooks to be able to get information from Qt Creator. If your executable is being built in the same directory the project lives in `currentPath()` will return it.

EDIT: I'll leave the part where I'm an idiot. Qt Creator has a set of API docs that point to `Core::FileManager::` and another for `Utils`. There's a number of functions in there for returning projects directory, what the current open file is, where it is and so on. There's no explicit 'what is the current absolute path' as far as a quick scan goes, but there's probably a way to query what's currently open. The API docs are here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-extending/qtcreator-api.html

Answer (score 1):

For latest QtCreator 3.4.0 API you can use this:

```
#include <projectexplorer/projecttree.h>
#include <projectexplorer/project.h>
#include <utils/fileutils.h>

ProjectExplorer::ProjectTree::currentProject()->projectDirectory().toString();
ProjectExplorer::ProjectTree::currentProject()->projectFilePath().toString();
```